# Can you control or target the style of a wrapped element?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example where I have several `inline-block` elements in a container element that will potentially shrink in width to the point where the elements within it will wrap.

I would like for there to be a small bit of space between each "row" or contained elements.  Using a `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` I get the space that I want.  However, there is a small bit of space either on the first or last row of elements.

Is there a way to target the line wrapped elements but not the first line?

```css
#container {
  width: 10em;
  background-color: blue;
}
#container > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#container > span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}
/*The following rule doesn't exist*/

#container > span:not(:first-row) {
  margin-top: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>some</span><span>text</span><span>of</span><span>some</span><span>elements</span><span>that</span><span>should</span><span>wrap</span>
</div>
```

Comment: *`:first-row`* where did that come from?

Comment: @Aziz Read the comment directly above that rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to target the line wrapped elements but not the first line?

No, not as of now.

> However, there is a small bit of space either on the first or last row of elements.

In most situations, you should be able to mitigate that by a negative margin on the container element, like so:

```css
#container {
  width: 10em;
  margin-bottom: -0.25em;
  background-color: blue;
}
#container > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0 0 .25em 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#container > span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

.test { background:red; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span>some</span><span>text</span><span>of</span><span>some</span><span>elements</span><span>that</span><span>should</span><span>wrap</span>
</div>
<div class="test">I am where I should be.</div>
```

(Added the red div to show that there’s no offset between it and the previous element.)

Comment: I really don't like using negative margins because it makes me feel like the style becomes less reusable.  However, this looks like the best answer since there is no style to target what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't target a bunch of spans as a row, especially if they're just wrapping when they don't fit on one line anymore.

You'd need to wrap the content in `<div class="row">` for example. Then you could say `.row:first-child { /* Custom styling */ }`.

This might be possible in the future, but as it stands it can't be done.

Comment: You could look into using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), might give you more control. But I don't think it would let you do exactly what you're trying to do now. Certainly not target a group of inline elements as a row, without any kind of wrapper etc.