# Indent line, if it was broken (since only little space is available)

Tags: html, css

I have two strings:

- foo bar baz
- abc def ghi

Both strings are in a column which shrinks as much as possible.

Now I see:

```
foo
bar
baz
abc
def
ghi
```

This is a bit hard to read.

Is there a way to show it like this:

```
foo
 bar
 baz
abc
 def
 ghi
```

I don't want to use bullet points here, since the would take additional place.

How to do this with HTML/CSS?

Comment: It is possible, but it would be an overkill honestly. Can't you use some kind of separator for each column to show that this column ends here?

Comment: A minimal code to know your structure could be helfull, from what I understand it's possible by adding some margin with `nth-child` selector, but it depends on the structure

Comment: Wrap each of those strings into a `div`, and then apply a `padding-left`, and a negative `text-indent`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you control or target the style of a wrapped element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610404/can-you-control-or-target-the-style-of-a-wrapped-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Resize the below container to see the result

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}

p {
  text-indent: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>foo bar baz</p>
  <p>abc def ghi</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. By simple `<ul> <li>`. You can see a demo here:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>foo
      <ul>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>baz</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>abc
      <ul>
        <li>def</li>
        <li>ghi</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case "foo bar baz" is one string which comes from the database. The string should not be split into a html list.